Parse data with patterns
If
arr = {1, {2, 3}};

we get {{2, 3}} from
Cases[arr, {a___, b___} :> {a, b}]

But if
arr = {1, {3}};

we get {{3}}, but I need {{"NoData", 3}} or {{0, 3}} in this case.
Updated
This is a bit philosophical addition.
If arr ={1, {3}}
what is a in
Cases[arr, {a___, b___} :> {a, b}]
?
Output is {{3}} and I tried
Cases[arr, {a___, b___} :> {Head@a, b}]
or something, but it not works.

I have down-voted this question because (1) you really didn't explain well-enough what you want to achieve, (2) you didn't give enough test cases, (3) you updated the text with a tangential question after already getting two answers.

@Domen, (3) is absolutely not true. And it's perfectly clear what I want to get, for simplest case: from {1, {2, 3}} OR from {1, {3}}. But as you like )

Try Cases[arr, {a___, b___} :> {Hold[a], Hold[b]}] to see what a and b match. Keep in mind Cases[] is trying to match each element of the list arr, namely 1 and {3}, to the pattern {a___, b___}. Obviously 1 won't match since it's not a list. The way the pattern matcher works is that a___ waits until the later patterns are done and gobbles up the leftovers (in the initial segment of the list); but b___ is greedy and eats everything up.

You can use Pattern with Optional value Missing or any other default value.
With
arr1 = {1, {2, 3}};
arr2 = {1, {3}};

Then
Cases[arr1, {a_ : Missing[], b_} :> {a, b}]


{{2, 3}}


and
Cases[arr2, {a_ : Missing[], b_} :> {a, b}]


{{Missing[], 3}}


Missing can be swapped out for your default value.
Cases[arr2, {a_ : "NoData", b_} :> {a, b}]


{{"NoData", 3}}


Hope this helps.

Thank you, construction a_:Missing[] is exactly what I need!

I somehow feel the question is an XY, but here goes:
PadLeft[Cases[arr, _List], {Automatic, 2}]
PadLeft[{Last@arr}, {Automatic, 2}]

PadLeft[{Last@arr}, {Automatic, 2}, "No data"]

The earlier XML version this Q&A certainly seemed less trivial.

Addendum:
Here's a straighforward C-like way:
If[Length[arr[[2]]] == 1,
 {{0, arr[[2, 1]]}},
 {arr[[2]]}
 ]


No, its not XY question , and I need universal solution, that in any ragged array replace {{x_, y_}, ___} to {{x, y},___} and {{y_}, ___} to {{0, y}, ___} or {{None, y}, ___}

@lesobrod What do you mean by universal? You have a list like {1, {2, 3}} or like {1, {3}}: That is, a list of length 2, consisting of a number followed by a list of length 1 or length 2. The output you ask for has the first element deleted and the second element padded on the left, if length 1, by 0 (or "No data", or in a comment None).  That's exactly what each code in my answer does, so they solve your problem.

Yes, thank you! Now I see that Cases and patterns are not work in this case, so using array parts analysis is best solution

Using Cases:
Cases[arr, {a___, b___} :> {0, b}]


{{0, 3}}

Or using Replace:
Replace[arr, {a_, b_List} :> List@*Join @@ {{0}, b}]


{{0, 3}}

Edit
To include the two cases, we can do the following:
f[arr_, pd_ : 0] := 
Replace[arr, {a_, b_List} :> 
If[Length@b == 1, {Join @@ {{pd}, b}}, {b}]];

f[{1, {2, 3}}]

(*{{2, 3}}*)

f[{1, {3}}]

(*{{0, 3}}*)

f[{1, {3}}, "No data"]

(*{{"No data", 3}}*)


The code should work universally for all cases! For arr={1, {2, 3}} it should print {{2,3}} and for arr={1, {3}} it should print {{0, 3}} or {{None, 3}}

See the update, please! :)

As MichaelE2 showed, PadLeft is useful here, and this is an alternate that does it directly as part of the rule in Cases.
myFunc = Cases[{a___, b___} :> PadLeft[{a, b}, 2, Missing[]]];

Demonstration:
test1 = {1, {2, 3}};
test2 = {1, {3}};
test3 = {1, {}};
test4 = {1, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
test5 = {1, {}, 2, {x}, {x, y}, 3, {x, y, z}};

myFunc@test1
(* {{2, 3}} *)

myFunc@test2
(* {{Missing[], 3}} *)

myFunc@test3
(* {{Missing[], Missing[]}} *)

myFunc@test4
(* {{3, 4}} *)

myFunc@test5
(* {{Missing[], Missing[]}, {Missing[], x}, {x, y}, {y, z}} *)

I suggest Missing rather than "no data", because there are standard ways of handling Missing (e.g. DeleteMissing). You could use Missing["no data"] to be a bit more explicit.
My third and fourth test cases are guesses.
This answer tries to preserve your rule {a___, b___} :> ..., but you might actually be able to craft a better pattern. We'd need to know more about your situation. For example, maybe you want {a___, b_} to disallow my third test case.
